# Why does std / boost::format cause this c_str() behaviour?

Tags: c++, boost, std

I'm using `boost::format` (not `std::` as I'm using c++98) to format a string that I'm passing to a `system()` call.

When getting the `c_str()` of the string created by `format`, it seems to terminate halfway along the string. The same sting created with the literal value does not have the same problem. What's going on here?

Using Boost **1.46.1** according to `BOOST_VERSION`.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const std::string my_str = "echo '/%1%/ some other stuff'";
    boost::format fmtr(my_str);
    fmtr % "sleep 3";   // should read: echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'

    std::cout << "1: " << fmtr.str() << "\n";          // 1. echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'  (OK)
    std::cout << "2: " << fmtr.str().c_str() << "\n";  // 2. echo '/sleep 3                     (BAD)

    // Try the c_str of a string not created through boost::format
    const std::string finished = "echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'";
    std::cout << "3: " << finished.c_str() << "\n";    // 3. echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'  (OK)

    // Try copying the string from format to see if that makes any difference (it doesn't)
    std::string copy = fmtr.str();
    std::cout << "4: " << copy.c_str() << "\n";        // 4. echo '/sleep 3                     (BAD)
    return 0;
}
```

Passing the `c_str()` to my `system()` call is resulting in the error:

```
sh -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

Presumably because it is finishing halfway along the string as well.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your behavior, looks like it is a bug for particular boost or stdc++ version, provide that info

Comment: you should include `<iostream>` and `<string>` not `<stdio.h>` and `main` must return `int`

Comment: I'm sorry, your usage seems to be correct, my bad.

Comment: I too cannot reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @Slava I've added boost version to the question: 1.46.1

Comment: If you can upgrade to 1.47.0 it appears to work: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ceOHPaYXbJ4iKBPF

Answer (score 0):

With proper includes your program works fine: [ideone](http://ideone.com/xVbxdO)

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string my_str = "echo '/%1%/ some other stuff'";
    boost::format fmtr(my_str);
    fmtr % "sleep 3";   // should read: echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'

    std::cout << "1: " << fmtr.str() << "\n";          // 1. echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'  (OK)
    std::cout << "2: " << fmtr.str().c_str() << "\n";  // 2. echo '/sleep 3                     (BAD)

    // Try the c_str of a string not created through boost::format
    const std::string finished = "echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'";
    std::cout << "3: " << finished.c_str() << "\n";    // 3. echo '/sleep 3/ some other stuff'  (OK)

    // Try copying the string from format to see if that makes any difference (it doesn't)
    std::string copy = fmtr.str();
    std::cout << "4: " << copy.c_str() << "\n";        // 4. echo '/sleep 3                     (BAD)
}
```

You should fix includes and return type of main and try again. If wrong behavior persist most probably you have broken version of c++ and/or boost library.